# Ayuda con el recorrido de una matriz en Python

Tags: python

Hola tengo una pregunta.

¿Como puedo recorrer una matriz en phyton en las columnas,
 la primera columna de arriba hacia abajo, la segunda columna de abajo hacia arriba, y así sucesivamente, en forma alternada?.

Lo e intentado todo, pero las columnas solo me recorren para abajo, cuando intento recorrer las columnas para arriba lo que se me recorre son las filas.

Yo creo que el error podría estar aquí

```
 def lacolumna():
     for C in range(1, NC+1, 2):
       for F in range(NF):
         print CAMINO[F][C-1],
       print
       if (C < NC):
         for K in range(NC, 0, -1):
           print CAMINO[C][K-1],
         print 

     print " "
     print " "
```

Answer (score 2):

Una forma relativamente sencilla de hacer esto es recurrir al modulo (resto de la división entera) para invertir el índice de las filas en la columnas impares.

```
camino = [[ 1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9],
          [10, 11, 12]
          ]


def imprimir_columnas(matriz):
    for columna in xrange(len(matriz[0])):
        for fila in xrange(len(matriz)):
            print matriz[fila - (columna % 2) * (fila + fila + 1)][columna],
        print

imprimir_columnas(camino)
```

**Salida**

> ```
> 1 4 7 10
> 11 8 5 2
> 3 6 9 12
> ```

En Python 3 sería:

```
def imprimir_columnas(matriz):
    for columna in range(len(matriz[0])):
        for fila in range(len(matriz)):
            print(matriz[fila - (columna % 2) * (fila + fila + 1)][columna], end=" ")
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Como el enunciado dice recorrerla y no guardarla como matriz o vector solo la imprimiremos,  para ello te recomiendo usar el operador `~`el cual es un operador unitario, su funcionamiento es invertir o negar a nivel de bits, para los enteros, `~x` es equivalente a `(-x) - 1` y esto nos ayudara a recorrer inversamente, por poner un ejemplo si aplicamos este operador a `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` cada uno de estos números la salida seria `-1, -2, -3, -4, -5`, que al momento de indexar en una lista seria como recorrerla inversamente.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
for i in range(len(a[0])):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if i%2==0:
            print(a[j][i])
        else:
            print(a[~j][i])
```

si `a` fuera:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

La salida seria:

```
[1, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6, 9]
```

Solo la recorre si deseas guardarla por ejemplo en otra matriz puedes usar `list comprehension` de python y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
[[a[j][i] if i%2==0 else a[~j][i] for j in range(len(a))] for i in range(len(a[0]))]
```

Lo cual produce la siguiente salida:

```
[[1, 4, 7],
 [8, 5, 2], 
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

Que creo que resuelve tu problema, espero haya entendido bien tu problema, si no házmelo saber